# How to mount XFS file system from inside initramfs?

Tags: xfs

1. Ubuntu 18.04 workstation (Desktop) locks up.
2. I reset the system and boot up to the `(initramfs)` prompt.
3. I reboot grml from a USB stick.
4. I activate the volume groups `(vgchange -a y ...)`
5. I mount the XFS file systems to clear the journal.
6. I reboot and it's OK.

Is there a way to clear the XFS journal from the `(initramfs)` prompt? It would save me some steps.

Comment: Not to snark but I recently installed FreeBSD on the second RAID-1 pair of disks and it has yet to lock up.

Comment: I transferred my home directory from Linux to FreeBSD by writing a backup as a tar file on NTFS on a firewire 800 disk.  I'm going to be testing FreeBSD more extensively to see if it more stable than Ubuntu Linux.